# Error When Start to Install React Native Project in IOS | Error Code 65

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I got an error that said, it works before I update my OS to Monterey. but after I update it just like this.

> Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited
> with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building
> your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwesomeProject.xcworkspace.

How can I solve this?
I try some references in Stackoverflow too, and I don't have a build folder in my project so it seems quite outdated some references in StackOverflow.

Comment: Did you try building in Xcode

Comment: i got same error did you fix it ?